# Can PM2 restart on http error?

Tags: http, monitoring, pm2

## What I'm after

I want to find a way to restart a process when the http response is not in the 2xx range.

## What is the setup

I have a PM2 process manager for a single app.

## What is wrong

The app sometimes refuses to reply to http requests or returns an error.

I want to detect those cases with health check and when it cannot be reached I want to restart the process.

The `watch` argument only covers the file changes on the drive and it's not a true configurable health check.